# Covert complexed list to flat list

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a long list complexed of numpy arrays and integers, below is an example:

```
[array([[2218.67288865]]), array([[1736.90215229]]), array([[1255.13141592]]), array([[773.36067956]]), array([[291.58994319]]), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

and i'd like to convert it to a regular list as so:

```
[2218.67288865, 1736.90215229, 1255.13141592, 773.36067956, 291.58994319, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

How can I do that efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generator for flattening the nested list:

```
def convert(obj):
    try:
        for item in obj:
            yield from convert(item)
    except TypeError:
        yield obj

result = list(convert(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

`list(itertools.from_iterable(itertools.from_iterable(...)))` should work for removing 2 levels of nesting: just add or remove copies of `itertools.from_iterable(...)` as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here the simplest seems to also be the fastest:

```
x = [array([[2218.67288865]]), array([[1736.90215229]]), array([[1255.13141592]]), array([[773.36067956]]), array([[291.58994319]]), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[y if y.__class__==int else y.item(0) for y in x]
# [2218.67288865, 1736.90215229, 1255.13141592, 773.36067956, 291.58994319, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

timeit(lambda:[y if y.__class__==int else y.item(0) for y in x])
# 2.198630048893392
```

Answer (score 0):

You can stick to `numpy` by using `np.ravel`:

```
np.hstack([np.ravel(i) for i in l]).tolist()
```

Output:

```
[2218.67288865,
 1736.90215229,
 1255.13141592,
 773.36067956,
 291.58994319,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0]
```